# Is it possible in React Typescript to use a component prop interface with another prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Basically, I want line `injectComponentProps: object` to be tied dynamically to whatever the injectComponent's prop interface is. In this case, it would be `injectComponentProps: InjectedComponentProps`, but I want it to be dynamic.

I.e Once prop injectComponent is set in , injectComponentProps is then defined to whatever injectComponent's components props are.

Is this possible?

```js
interface InjectedComponentProps {
  variant: string
  size: number
}

const InjectedComponent: React.FC<InjectedComponentProps> = (props) => {
  return <Text {...props}>hello</Text>
}

interface ComponentProps {
  injectComponent: React.ReactType
  injectComponentProps: object
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const InjectedComponent = props.injectComponent
  return (
    <>
      <InjectedComponent {...props.injectComponentProps}/>
    </>
  )
}


const Main: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Component
      injectComponent={InjectedComponent}
      injectComponentProps={{ variant: 'footnote', size: 14 }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Isn't it about generics? (or I don't understand the question). Something like `interface ComponentProps<T>` then `injectComponentProps: T` ?

Comment: Take a look at this [article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/passing-generics-to-jsx-elements-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
interface InjectedComponentProps {
  variant: string
  size: number
}

const InjectedComponent: React.FC<InjectedComponentProps> = (props) => {
  return null
}

interface ComponentProps<T> {
  injectComponent: React.FC<T>
  injectComponentProps: T
}

const Component = <T extends {}>(props: ComponentProps<T>): JSX.Element => {
  const InjectedComponent = props.injectComponent
  return (
    <>
      <InjectedComponent {...props.injectComponentProps}/>
    </>
  )
}


const Main: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Component
      injectComponent={InjectedComponent}
      injectComponentProps={{ variant: 'footnote', size: 14 }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the type simply as `object`, you should try modifying `ComponentProps` into a [constrained generic](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) component that infers the props of its type parameter.

The generic `GetProps` uses [conditional type inference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to infer props from a component, i.e., infer type parameter of a generic.

```
type GetProps<C extends React.ComponentType<any>> = C extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P : any

interface InjectedComponentProps {
  variant: string
  size: number
}

const InjectedComponent: React.FC<InjectedComponentProps> = (props) => {
  return <Text {...props}>hello</Text>
}

// make this a generic type
interface ComponentProps<C extends React.ComponentType<any>> {
  injectComponent: C
  injectComponentProps: GetProps<C>
}

// and use it here
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps<typeof InjectedComponent>> = (props) => {
  const InjectedComponent = props.injectComponent
  return (
    <>
      <InjectedComponent {...props.injectComponentProps}/>
    </>
  )
}

const Main: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Component
      injectComponent={InjectedComponent}
      injectComponentProps={{ variant: 'footnote', size: 14 }}
    />
  )
}
```